# How to print pdf.js document?

Tags: javascript, printing, pdf.js

I've generated a document with pdf.js and it shows correctly. I'don't have print button. How to add the button to allow users to print it ?
I was using Chrome.

Comment: once displayed, offer <button onclick=window.print()>Print Page</button> - embed in an iframe if that's all you want to print.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try using the javascript-function `window.print();`, which opens the print-dialog.

You will have to add an button to your html, which triggers the command - its not possible within the pdf.

For this reason, you will need an iFrame, and use something like this:

```
function printIt() {
    var wnd = window.open('http://your-pdf-url');
    wnd.print();
}

<input type="button" value="Print" onclick=printIt()>
```

`window.print()` wouldn't work, because it would also print the surrounding html.

**EDIT:**

From your comment, I now know, that you want to print the content of a canvas-element - which is much easier.

You don't need an iframe, you can put the button on the same page, and use `window.print();`.

In order to only print the canvas-element, and to hide the surroundings (like the button), you can use css-Syntax like this:

```
@media print
{    
    .no-print, .no-print *
    {
        display: none !important;
    }
}
```

`@media print` specifies css-code, which only applies for a webpage, if it gets printed. If you now asign the class `.no-print` to everything except the canvas-element, only your pdf will be printed.

You can also use this css-code, if it's easier:

```
@media print
{    
    *
    {
        display: none;
    }
    canvas 
    {
        display: inline;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but the problem is that I'don't have url for the pdf. I got the base64 representation of pdf from server, converted it to array and created pdf.js document from it.

Comment: @Dejo: You are accessing your pdf via the browser - so there must be an url, which starts generating the pdf. If you put it into an iframe, you can also use `var wnd = document.getElementById("myframe").contentWindow;`

Comment: Thx, but it would not be so easy, because it is rendered in the canvas element.

Comment: then use window.print() and a few line of print-only css to hide the non-pdf stuff.

Comment: not working, It's showing a blank page. 
Shouldn't be waiting for the pdf to load?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep everything in line and mess with jquery as little as possible you can try to something like:

```
<a href="#PATH_TO_PDF.pdf" target="_blank"  onclick="window.print()"> print PDF </a>
```

Comment: This will just print the parent page

Answer (score -2):

I have been looking for a solution to this for so long and then I landed on this JS plugin:

http://printjs.crabbly.com/

It works like a charm!

Comment: I wasn't the one who downvoted, but I must point out that this library won't work on FireFox.