# Print html element with a pdf displayed with PDF.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, printing, pdf.js

Is there any possibility to print a PDF rendered with PDF.js?

If I put the PDF in a div, and than I ma trying to print with jQuery printarea only the div, what it will printed is a blank page.

Has anyone any idea?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21465368/how-to-print-pdf-js-document

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14401965/printing-pdf-using-pdf-js

Comment: Possible Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16239513/print-pdf-directly-from-javascript

Comment: Try the answers provided by those linked questions